# How to create custom mongo health check in spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot-actuator

How to disable default mongo health check in spring boot actuator and create custom mongo health check url like ../manage/mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**application.properties**

> management.health.mongo.enabled=false
>   endpoints.mongo.enabled=true

**MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint.java**

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "endpoints.mongo", ignoreUnknownFields = true)
@Component
public class MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint extends AbstractEndpoint<Map<String, String>> 
{

    @Inject
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;


    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    private static final Map<String, String> UP = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("mongo.status", "UP");
    }};

    private static final Map<String, String> DOWN = new HashMap<String, String>() {{
        put("mongo.status", "DOWN");
    }};


    public MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint() {
        super("mongo", false);
    }

    public MongoDBHealthCheckEndPoint(Map<String, ? extends Object> mongo) {
        super("mongo", false);
    }

    public Map<String, String> invoke() {
        try {
            return (new MongoHealthIndicator(mongoTemplate).health().getStatus().equals(Status.UP)) ? UP : DOWN;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("mongo database is down", e);
            return DOWN;
        }
    }
}
```